# jquery autocomplete how to get the selected index

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery's autocomplete.  The values in the array are from an ajax call. the ajax file returns a one dimensional array, which I use to build the autocomplete.  How do I get the selected index of the autocomplete box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
  //access ui.item for anything that was selected you want.
});
```